# AWS Beanstalk - Passenger Standalone not serving web pages after Rails 4.2.1 migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Rails 3.2.21 app was running fine on AWS Beanstalk under Passenger Standalone 4.0.53.  I migrated the app to Rails 4.2.1 and got it passing all tests on my local development machine (Ubuntu, WEBrick).  I deployed it to Beanstalk (`aws.push`), the deploy succeeds (copied from /ondeck to /current) and:  nothing.  I browse to the site and see a blank page.  No 404 error, nothing.

On the old version, I had pre-compiled assets locally. This time, I let Beanstalk run `'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp`. I see in eb-activity.log that this succeeded, and I see those assets in var/app/current/public/assets. But this isn't about not serving public assets, it's about not serving *anything*.

So yes, there is a /public directory as required by Passenger. There is also a /tmp directory. And here's the **config.ru** that Rails created:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

Also in eb-activity.log, I see this message that seems to indicate Passenger is working:

```
+ service passenger restart
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /var/app/support/pids/passenger.pid
Log file: /var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0/

Serving in the background as a daemon.
```

But when I run `curl -o - http://0.0.0.0` from the console, it just goes to the next line--no headers or other web content is returned.

I can run `rails c` to start a Rails console on the AWS machine. Works fine, has database access.

I've re-run `eb init` on my development machine to make sure it connects correctly, although the `git aws.push` has always worked to upload a new version.

I terminated the EC2 instance and let the load balancer start a new instance. That built successfully. The first time it came up (and only then), I saw some error messages in **/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log**:

```
[ 2015-06-17 01:03:54.8281 2556/7fd8941b8740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { [redacted] }
[ 2015-06-17 01:03:55.2388 2559/7ff254abe740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2555/generation-0/request
[ 2015-06-17 01:03:55.9207 2567/7fcb54570740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.2555/generation-0/logging
[ 2015-06-17 01:03:55.9209 2556/7fd8941b8740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2015/06/17 01:03:57 [error] 2575#0: *3 "/var/app/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
2015/06/17 01:04:02 [error] 2575#0: *4 "/var/app/current/public/app_check/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.31.21.97, server: _, request: "GET /app_check/ HTTP/1.1", host: "172.31.25.47"
[ 2015-06-17 01:06:10.4000 21317/7f433c999740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { [redacted] }
[ 2015-06-17 01:06:10.4047 21320/7f414cdd5740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.21316/generation-0/request
[ 2015-06-17 01:06:10.4090 21325/7f87c44f2740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.21316/generation-0/logging
[ 2015-06-17 01:06:10.4092 21317/7f433c999740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
```

Usually, **passenger.log** is empty, even after I try to access the site.

I just tried setting the log level to DEBUG. After Passenger restarted, it printed this in **passenger.log**:

```
[ 2015-06-18 17:52:28.3921 631/7f42fc9ce700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /var/app/current started on PID 666, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.627/generation-0/backends/preloader.p23dhh
```

Why isn't Passenger serving web pages? How can I troubleshoot this?

**Update 6/18/2015**

Tried pre-compiling assets on development machine and then deploying. Didn't help.

**Update 6/19/2015**

I now have a Rails 4.2.1 test app successfully running under the same Beanstalk environment (64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.1.0 running Ruby 2.0 - Passenger Standalone). I see that on the test app, there are four Passenger processes:

- PassengerHelper (running as webapp)
- PassengerLogging (running as webapp)
- PassengerWatchdog (running as root)
- PassengerHelper (running as root)

The pid returned by `service passenger status` corresponds to the PassengerHelper running as root.

On the failing live app, there is only one Passenger process:

- PassengerHelper (running as webapp)

The pid returned by `service passenger status` does not correspond to an active process.

So apparently, three of the four Passenger processes are crashing after they start. So far I have not been able to find any corresponding error logs, so I don't know why they crash.

Comment: You are working with 2 things that I hate. Passenger and Beanstalk. Just a suggestion Have you tried to run an EC2 without Beanstalk with all the config you need to run Passenger, then loading your application see if it response? It will take a bit of time however you might find out that a setting might be missing. Also don't use ELB in this test server. Just a bare bone. Good Luck

Comment: I'm too far down the Beanstalk path to go back easily. I did set up a test app yesterday which is actively failing with a 404 error. Having trouble finding out how to increase the log level for Passenger Standalone--it still says it's starting with 0. Also can't figure out how/where it determines which Rails page to start from, though I assume that is somehow supposed to be automatic.

Comment: Solved the 404 error on the test app. For some reason, Passenger would not respond to `GET /` with the default Rails template. Once I added a custom home page and a `root :to` it in routes.rb, the test app started responding properly. My real app already has a `root :to` so that is not the issue.

Comment: Passenger author here. I think you are starting Passenger Standalone in the wrong directory. It appears that your app lives in /var/app/current. But the `service passenger start` output seems to indicate that you started Passenger Standalone in /var/app/support. Or did you just customize the paths of the pid file and log file?

Where exactly is your config.ru located?

Comment: In both the live and test apps, Beanstalk starts the passenger service with this command: `passenger start /var/app/current --nginx-version 1.6.2 -p 80 --pid-file /var/app/support/pids/passenger.pid -d -e production --user webapp --log-file /var/app/support/logs/passenger.log`. Also in both apps, config.ru is in /var/app/current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to increase the logging level for Passenger Standalone (blogged [here](http://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2015/06/changing-the-passenger-standalone-log-level/)). From the log, I could see that the web server was responding to the Beanstalk health check with 301 redirects. That meant that the load balancer thought the app was dead, so it was sending 503 errors back to the browser, which displayed a blank page.

The 301 redirect tipped me to the `force_ssl` configuration. I had it configured as follows in production.rb:

```
config.force_ssl = true
config.ssl_options = { exclude: proc { |env| env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?('/app_check') } }
```

The second line, following [this post](http://justinleitgeb.com/rails/easy-application-wide-ssl-configuration-in-rails-3-2/), is supposed to allow the health check (which only works on http) to bypass the `force_ssl`> However, the `exclude` option has been removed from Rail 4.2 per [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5515#issuecomment-11864757). Without the exclude, the health check failed and the load balancer wouldn't serve the app.

The default Elastic Beanstalk behavior, if you don't specify a health check URL, is to simply ping the server on port 22.  However I prefer that the health check actually confirm that the web server is working by loading a web page.

I've implemented this workaround:

Remove `config.force_ssl` and `config.ssl_options` from production.rb.

Add the following to application.rb, assuming that the health check is accessible from StaticPagesController#health_check:

```
force_ssl if: :require_ssl? # see private method below for conditions

private

def require_ssl?
  Rails.env.production? && !(controller_name == "static_pages" && action_name == "health_check")
end
```

I may still have a Passenger or Nginx issue since I still only have one Passenger process running, and its PID doesn't match the PID from `service passenger status`.  But at least the web server is serving my site again.